# Problems with angular-ui-router - I cannot apply a filter to a repeat in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ngresource

I have an issue that only occurs when I load directives as part of a angular-ui-router state. When I add the directives directly to index.html everything works as expected.

Here's a plunker that demonstrates the issue I'm having:
http://plnkr.co/edit/EzvTOiSzaf6jjCsBKM1e?p=preview

I have a Resource `personResource` that returns an array of objects.
The Controller `personController` queries the Resource, and saves the results into `$scope.people`.
This populates a template `list-people.html` which is loaded in a directive `listPeople`.

What I'm having problems with is another directive `filterPeople` contains radio buttons with options to filter the list.

The expected result is that if I select an option, it will only display those rows where the row's value matches the option value. What is actually happening is that all of the data is displayed no matter what I select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scope issue, your templates have their own child scopes that can't see values in each other, so when you set the `personFilter.color` in one template, your template using it as a filter doesn't know about it.  You can use angularjs batarang or just insert a simple binding to debug these issues ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/EzvTOiSzaf6jjCsBKM1e?p=preview)):

```
</tbody></table>personFilter json: {{personFilter|json}
```

To fix the problem you can set the personFilter object on the parent scope and both children will use the inherited object.  Just realize that if you set the object on a child scope instead of just a property, it will only set that value on the one child scope and the other scopes will continue to use the inherited object.  You should probably put the controller on a parent.  Your controller is being instantiated for both the content and sidebar, so you are querying your people twice even though the data isn't used in your sidebar...

Comment: What's weird is that I can put a `$scope.$watch` for 'personFilter' in my controller, and it correctly sees the value  being updated from the child template. If personFilter was scoped to the child view, then shouldn't the parent not be able to see its values?
See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/16huKiaZeZMudrbn9LwU?p=preview
personFilter is output to the console.

Comment: Update: So one thing that makes it work is by initializing the variables using `$scope.$parent.people = ...` `$scope.$parent.personFilter = ...`. I'm just still confused by one thing - I thought that by specifying the same controller for  state and directives, they would also share the same scope. What happens when the same controller is specified for different objects? Do they each get their own instance of the same controller, with different scopes?

Comment: Without the `controller as ...` syntax I don't think there is an instance of the controller, the controller function just executes and can modify whatever scope is passed to it.  If you log in the controller function you can see it is being run on two different scopes, and in the watch only one is being updated. ([***plnkr***](http://plnkr.co/edit/KXSx9YAoDFDJKNsT0Uks?p=preview)).  If you use the angularjs batarang chrome extension you can see all the scopes created, or by inspecting the html you can see any element with the `ng-scope` attribute or class has it's own scope.